# How do I connect C# with Postgres?

Tags: c#, postgresql

How do I connect C# with Postgres? I installed the npgsql data provider but couldn't make it work. Are there more examples than the ones in the Postgres site?

Comment: I assume you actually mean Postgres rather than Postgre. If you've already got a driver but can't get it to work, it's worth saying exactly what happens when you try.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003/c-net-postgresql

Comment: Make sure that you can connect with the postgres console client, or pgAdmin3 first. Adjusting postgres's default connection permissions is usually necessary if you've just installed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# .NET + PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003/c-sharp-net-postgresql)

Answer (score 35):

You want the [NPGSQL](http://www.npgsql.org/) library. Your only other alternative is ODBC.

Answer (score 16):

If you want an recent copy of npgsql, then go here

http://www.npgsql.org/

This can be installed via package manager console as

**PM> Install-Package Npgsql**